# Omnet++ IDE doesn't run simulation macOS

Tags: macos, omnet++

I installed omnet++ IDE following the steps in the installation guide. I verified it works by running the aloha sample simulation. However, if I start the IDE from the Finder icon (.app), which is by default located in **~/omnetpp-installation-folder/ide**, i'm not able to run any simulation and i receive the following error at startup

[image: Startup error omnetpp]

But, it's even worse when i try to run the simulation...

```
This application failed to start because
it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin
"cocoa" in "".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Simulation terminated with exit code: 134
Working directory: /Users/AlessandroCornacchia/omnetpp-5.4.1/samples/tictoc 
Command line: tictoc -m -u Qtenv omnetpp.ini

Environment variables:
PATH=/Users/AlessandroCornacchia/omnetpp-5.4.1/bin::/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/AlessandroCornacchia/omnetpp-5.4.1/lib::
OMNETPP_IMAGE_PATH=/Users/AlessandroCornacchia/omnetpp-5.4.1/images
```

What's strange is that if I run from terminal everything goes straightforward and I'm perfectly able to simulate..

Thank you for the support

Answer (score 2):

Start the IDE from the command line (after executing `. setenv`) by typing:

$ omnetpp

Do **not** start the IDE from the Finder. The reason is that the IDE requires some environment variables that are set in the `setenv` script and those are not present when it is started from Finder. Additionally, macOS quarantines all graphical apps that were downloaded from the internet (including the IDE). This means that when you start the .app file, you seem to be running it from the installation folder, but in fact macOS remaps it to a temporary volume with random name, which breaks the whole IDE as it cannot find the OMNET rood directory. This is worked around in the the `omnetpp` scripts (in OMNETPP_ROOT/ide) but that is not executed if you start directly from the finder.

Comment: Ok  I supposed it was something related to the environment variables. I was not convinced exhaustively for the only reason that in the installation guide it's indicated the way for creating a desktop icon, so why suggesting something will not work for sure.. Thank you a lot for your detailed explanation